# Converting Lists within Pandas Dataframe into New DataFrame

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df =

   col1                col2
0  [0.1,0.2,0.3]       [1,2,3]
1  [0.5,0.6,0.7]       [11,12,13]
```

My goal: to re-create data frame from index 0:

```
new_df = 
   new_col1    new_col2
0   0.1          1
1   0.2          2
2   0.3          3
```

What I tried was trying to access row by row:

```
new_col1 = df.col1[0]
new_col2 = df.col2[0]
```

But new_col1 results in below instead of a list. So I am unsure how to approach this.

```
0    [0.1,0.2,0.3]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way by using `apply`.

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).loc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the list() function for this

```
>>> new_col1
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
>>> new_col1_=list(new_col1)
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
>>> type(new_col1_)
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new DataFrame by select first row by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for new columns names:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0].tolist(), index=df.columns).T.add_prefix('new_')
print (df1)
   new_col1  new_col2
0       0.1       1.0
1       0.2       2.0
2       0.3       3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([new_col1, new_col2]).transpose()
```

If you want to add column names,

```
new_df.columns = ["new_col1","new_col2"]
```